How to solve such an integral?
Let $f(x)$ be a continious and non-negative function such that $$\int_x^\frac{\pi}{2} f(t-x)f(t)dt=\cos^4(x).$$
Calculate $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x)dx.$$

What have you tried?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

@SeanRoberson Just find that if x=0,we have $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f^2(t)dt=1$,but I can't find relationship between goal and formula above.Adjusting the variable range also does not help.
